# Does my DynamoDb connection Close every time?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to understand if my Dynamodb connection closes each time I execute a command

```
const dboperation1 = async(param) =>{
    const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    const result = await docClient.query(params).promise();
    return result

}
```

Considering the above example each time I call dboperation1 would it lead to connection establishment to DynamoDb first.

If so how can I keep some connections open already so that I could readily use them to query the db avoiding the extra time taken to set up the connection ? basically trying to avoid the initial handshake that takes place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> By default, the default Node.js HTTP/HTTPS agent creates a new TCP
> connection for every new request. To avoid the cost of establishing a
> new connection, you can reuse an existing connection.

All AWS SDK calls use http(s) connections. we just need to build a keepAlive Agent and pass it to httpOptions when initializing a client.
This is applicable for all other AWS SDK clients , not just DynamoDB.

```
const agent = new https.Agent({
  keepAlive: true
});
```

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-reusing-connections.html) is the documentation

Below is an example

```
import { Agent as httpsAgent } from 'https';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
var docClient = new DB.DocumentClient({
    httpOptions: {
        connectTimeout: 4000,
        agent: new httpsAgent({ keepAlive: true }),
    },
    logger: console,
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
    convertEmptyValues: true,
});
```